# Calculate the distance of a falling object and terminal speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, free-fall

I have a homework problem that I would like to verify that I am doing it correctly. If anyone could help me see where I'm going wrong with the steps, I would really appreciate it.

(a) Consider a skydiver in free fall that starts the fall from rest. Calculate the distance the skydiver needs to cover for his speed to equal the speed of sound.
He jumped from an altitude of 39,044m above the ground.
He reached a speed of 373m/s
Speed of sound = 308m/s.
Skydiver's mass = 200 kg

First I used v = at and plugged in 308 =9.8t to get the time at which the speed equaled 308m/s, then I plugged that into y = (1/2)gt^2, getting 4831.2 m

(b) What is the skydiver's terminal speed? 
Air density at ground level = 1.2kg/m^3
Cross-sectional area = 0.7m^2
C = .486

I just plugged in all of the information for the terminal speed equation and got 98m/s for the terminal speed

Comment: Actually, the speed of sound is a little bit higher than that, but, I know, the problem says that. Ok, about the data  " He reached a speed of 373m/s " I suppose that the only useful information from here is that, in some moment he went faster that the speed of sound... and just that. Finally, yeah! everything seems alright to me.

Comment: Do you think you're wrong?  Did you discuss with  your instructor?  Is there a specific concept which confuses you? I don't know what you're asking about re: physics. We don't check work here without a **specific** question about a **specific** confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you're getting the numbers $373$ and $308\,\mathrm{m/s}$. Which one is the speed of sound? If part **a)** assumes that the skydiver's free fall is in the absence of air resistance, then your answer is correct. If it doesn't assume that, then the skydiver will never reach the speed of sound, since the terminal velocity you (correctly) calculated in part **b)** is much less than the speed of sound!

Comment: Both numbers were given. 373 is the velocity he reached, and 308 is the speed of sound. I should have mentioned that, but yes, (a) is in the absence of air resistance. Thank you for your answer!